# KML balloon height style in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, coding-style, kml, cdata, google-earth

I'm trying to limit the description balloon height in the following KML for use with Google Maps. In Google Earth, this is achieved by using the style element of a div wrapper, so the following KML works fine. However, when referenced via Google Maps, the height attribute is stripped out resulting in a large balloon when the maker is clicked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"> <Placemark>
    <name>Test Mark</name>
    <description>
       <![CDATA[
        <div style="height:150px;overflow:auto">
          <table>
            <tr><td>Row 1</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 2</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 3</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 4</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 5</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 6</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 7</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 8</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 9</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 10</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 11</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 12</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 13</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 14</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 15</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 16</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 17</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 18</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 19</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 20</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 21</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 22</td><td>some data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 23</td><td>some data</td></tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      ]]>
    </description>
    <Point>
    <coordinates>1,23</coordinates>
    </Point>   </Placemark> </kml>
```

​[Here](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&geocode=&q=https%3a%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fuc%3Fid%3D0ByaeSpZvpEFeYmNlYTZmZTYtYzkwYy00MWM2LThmOTEtMzBiYjM4NDAyM2Iy&aq=&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=35.821085,67.324219&ie=UTF8&ll=23.030451,0.994263&spn=0.114851,0.154324&z=13) is how the KML looks in Google Maps

In my project, it is feasible that the tables I'm creating in the balloon description's could be quite long, so I need to make the balloon contents scrollable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just swap height for max-height like so:

```
<div style="max-height: 150px; overflow: auto">
```